# How can I return a dynamic text

Tags: javascript, react-native

I did an "IF" to do dynamic text, if is null do show something,else shows another.But it is returning blank.What I did wrong ?

```js
<View style={styles.rightContainer}>
    { () =>{        
        if(this.state.sicafSource.IdStatusManutencao == null){

            return(
                <View style={[{paddingHorizontal:10, marginTop:5,borderRadius:5},this.ReturnColor("Não achei na api","ATIVO")]}>
                        <Text style={[{ textAlign: 'right' }, styles.swipeCardRightTextS]}>
                                Sem informação 
                        </Text>
                </View>
            );

    }
    else{

        return(
            <View style={[{paddingHorizontal:10, marginTop:5,borderRadius:5},this.ReturnColor("Não achei na api","ATIVO")]}>
                <Text style={[{ textAlign: 'right' }, styles.swipeCardRightTextS]}>
                    api resposta true 
                </Text>
            </View>          

        );
    }
}
    }
</View>
```

Comment: Start by cleaning up your indentation to make your code more clear. Also, why is the `if` statement inside an anonymous function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) in JSX. Everything within `{}` needs to be an expression (something that returns a value). If's are a statement.

- http://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html

```js
{this.state.sicafSource.IdStatusManutencao == null ? (
    <div>Return this when true</div>
) : (
    <div>Return this when false</div>
)
```

Comment: In addition to this, the fat arrow function `() => { ... }` is also not an expression.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to call your anonymous function so that the `if` statement can be evaluated:

```
() => {
  // ...
} () // add these
```

However using a ternary operator or boolean operators is cleaner. Instead of

```
if (A) {
  B;
} else {
  C;
}
```

You can do either

```
A ? B : C
```

or

```
A && B || C
```